# On using "whether it be" with plurals

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I use data to describe plurals (Xs or Ys). Is it correct to use `whether it be` in the following description?

> The data, whether it be Xs or Ys, are collected from users.

Or shall I use whether they are?

Comment: That's fine. But note that "data", although officially plural, is most often treated as singular, so it should be "is collected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *data* can be taken as either singular or plural. Depending on how you interpret it, the subject and verb need to be in agreement.

You can't mix them inconsistently as in the question:

> ✘ The data, whether **it** be Xs or Ys, **are** collected from users.

Depending on your interpretation, either of these is correct:

> ✔ The data, whether **it** be Xs or Ys, **is** collected from users.
>   ✔ The data, whether **they** be Xs or Ys, **are** collected from users.

---

Of course, you could also rephrase the sentence in various ways:

> ✔ The data, whether **it consists** of Xs or Ys, **is** collected from users.
>   ✔ The **points of data**, whether **they consist** of Xs or Ys, **are** collected from users.